# Thread Animation Example not working

Tags: java, swing, animation, thread-sleep

I was trying to follow these tutorials http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/animation/ and none of the three examples on that page seem to be working for me. One of them uses a swing timer, one uses the utility timer, and the last and supposedly most effective and accurate according to the page uses a thread to animate.

I will show you the one using the thread, since it is the way that I think I will be doing thing's when using animation for making games.

ThreadAnimationExample.java (in the tutorial it is called star.java but obviously that wont work)

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ThreadAnimationExample extends JFrame {

public ThreadAnimationExample() {

    add(new Board());

    setTitle("Star");               

    pack();
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {                
            JFrame ex = new ThreadAnimationExample();
            ex.setVisible(true);                
        }
    });
}
}
```

Board.java (the main class)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board extends JPanel
    implements Runnable {

private final int B_WIDTH = 350;
private final int B_HEIGHT = 350;
private final int INITIAL_X = -40;
private final int INITIAL_Y = -40;
private final int DELAY = 25;

private Image star;
private Thread animator;
private int x, y;

public Board() {

    loadImage();
    initBoard();
}

private void loadImage() {

    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("star.png");
    star = ii.getImage();
}

private void initBoard() {

    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(B_WIDTH, B_HEIGHT));
    setDoubleBuffered(true);

    x = INITIAL_X;
    y = INITIAL_Y;
}

@Override
public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();

    animator = new Thread(this);
    animator.start();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    drawStar(g);
}

private void drawStar(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(star, x, y, this);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    g.dispose();
}

private void cycle() {

    x += 1;
    y += 1;

    if (y > B_HEIGHT) {

        y = INITIAL_Y;
        x = INITIAL_X;
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {

    long beforeTime, timeDiff, sleep;

    beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while (true) {

        cycle();
        repaint();

        timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
        sleep = DELAY - timeDiff;

        if (sleep < 0) {
            sleep = 2;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: ..and what is your question?

Comment: Wow, sorry, I should really elaborate more. The star simply isn't being drawn to the screen. I've tested all the methods to see if they are running with System.out.println's and everything seems to be being called correctly. I've tried multiple image files, I am putting them right next to my .java files in the package folder.

Comment: Okay, I found the source of the problem... I tried using an image file elsewhere on my computer and it worked.. but earlier I was drawing image files from my package folder where my .java's are without any animation and it was working fine, so I am still not sure why that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse you should create a source folder and add that image to the source folder. Then you could use this:

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("/imageName.png") );
```

Comment: Cool, I did that. Thanks!